# month number of 2 years date power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 years dates in a column and want to calculate month number like

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14...24

Need dax or any other way
New to power bi

---

Comment: Show input data and expected output clearly.

Comment: I have date column with 2 years dates and the output should be a column which will show out put like 1,2,3...12,13...24 month

Comment: Show snapshot of your data. "date column with 2 years dates" - what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a calculated column like this:

```
Sequential Month Number = 
    VAR _minYear = YEAR(MIN(myTable[Date]))
RETURN
    MONTH(myTable[Date])+(YEAR(myTable[Date])-_minYear)*12
```